# Need to run shell script on linux machine which uses sqlcmd but machine doesn't have SQL Server 2008 installed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, shell, sqlcmd

We have a scenario where we need to run a shell script on a Linux machine. This shell script internally uses `sqlcmd` but the machine doesn't have SQL Server 2008 installed.

Can anyone help me which tools/scripts/commmands that are required so that I can install/copy paste that client to run this script?

It would be helpful to provide link of such client so that i can download and give a try.

Shell script contains :

```
sqlcmd -S $Server -U $USER -P $PASSWORD  -i AggregateChannels.sql
```

Thanks.

Comment: `sqlcmd.exe` is a Windows executable, so it isn't clear why you expect to run it from Linux. Can you clarify what you're trying to do and why you are using a Linux box here?

Comment: Are you looking for a commandline tool to access SQL Server from a Linux box? If yes, this might help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/19165/1822

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple Google gives me [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568447.aspx):

> The sqlcmd utility is available in the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL
>   Server on Linux.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451.aspx) for installation info.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use a Linux version of sql tools in docker to connect to your SQL server.

See: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-tools